# How do I remove the logoff option from the Windows XP shutdown dialog?

Tags: windows-xp, shutdown, logoff

I have a handful of Windows XP workstations available for public use. They are configured to autologin at startup.

However, for some reason when some users finish using the workstation, they have the annoying habit of going to the Start menu, clicking the shutdown button, and selecting "logoff". So, the next person who wants to use the computer is unable to because they can't log in.

Is there a way to remove the logoff option in the shutdown dialog?

The logoff button is already hidden on the Start menu.

I do not want to disable logoff entirely. I would still like to access it from the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> window to perform maintenance tasks as another user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may also want to consider the **ForceAutoLogon** value. This value tells Windows to automatically log back on (with the autologon credentials) when someone logs off.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon

Name: ForceAutoLogon
Type: REG_SZ
Value: 1
```

Comment: Interesting. But--if I use that, there's still the issue of being able to log off and log on as an administrator for maintenance.

Comment: Hold down the Shift key while it's logging off and it won't log back on.

Comment: Looks like your suggestion works as advertised. Thanks!

Comment: I tested this value on Windows 7 and still works! Thanks a lot. It's very useful to ensure a user is logged in on the machine always, which is required to run a scheduled task which needs a user session to run correctly.

Answer (score 4):

According to [technet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itprovirt/thread/2bb6ae34-c764-469f-8eb5-06f20a17ffd4), you need to edit the registry.

Here are the steps, in case you are unable to view the link:

To disable Log off

1. Type regedit in Start menu search box and then hit enter
2. Navigate to the following key:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer

3. In the right-pane, create a new DWORD value named StartMenuLogOff and set value to 1.

To disable switch user

4. Navigate to the following key:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE \Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System

5. In the right-pane, create a new DWORD value named HideFastUserSwitching and set value to 1.

To disable Lock

6. Under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE \Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System, create a new DWORD value named DisableLockWorkstation and set value to 1.

Then, please restart the computer.

Comment: I don't want to disable the logoff feature entirely. Just hide it from the "windows shutdown" dialog.

Comment: Personally, logging out when done (especially in a multiple user environment) is a really good practice that I think we should encourage. Perhaps we can take a step back and see what we need to accomplish here? Maybe the computer can reboot and auto login whenever someone logs out?

Comment: This is a public workstation. Users do not have individual accounts. The only users are the administrative user I use for maintenance and the user that is set for autologon for public use.

Comment: How do you get rid of cookies and such between user sessions? Window Washer? How about setting up a guest account that users can log into without requiring a password? You are using a fairly advanced operating system (not being sarcastic at all). Perhaps, [Guest Account](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300489) might work for you? This may sound hypocritical but personally I try to stay away from directly modifying the registry whenever possible. Perhaps even make the computer [automatically login to the guest account](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/auto-login-guest-c-t2432906.html)?

Comment: The workstations are in a domain and settings enforced through group policy. The browser deleted browser history/cookies/data on exit. I can distribute registry changes through group policy, so I'm not worried about that (especially since what I'm trying to do is not an option which is available in group policy)

Comment: Sounds like something that ought to be in Group Policy. Perhaps you would like to look into the option of remoting into the machine to perform administrative tasks instead of walking up an down the aisles?

Comment: It would be nice if it were in group policy, but it isn't. Yes, I can access the workstations remotely, but depending on where I am and what I'm working on, it's sometimes easier to access the workstation directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable logoff option in Windows XP from 'Start Menu' using group policy editor

**[Removing Log Off from the Start Menu](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverGP/thread/5054f70b-5376-4723-b8dc-6bc2627be86e/)**

- Start Group Policy Editor (Start > Run > “gpedit.msc”)
- In the left panel, go to User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Start Menu and Taskbar
- In the right panel, enable Remove Logoff on the Start Menu

[**Removing Log Off from Task Manager**](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverGP/thread/5054f70b-5376-4723-b8dc-6bc2627be86e/)

- Start Group Policy Editor (Start > Run > “gpedit.msc”)
- In the left panel, go to User Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Ctrl+Alt+Del Options
- In the right panel, enable Remove Logoff

Comment: See edit--The logoff button on the start menu is already hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the directions here and reboot http://www.pctools.com/guides/registry/detail/9/

to remove logoff :-

Start the Registry Editor (go to Start, Run and type Regedt32). Find the key

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\policies\Explorer]
create a new dword called NoLogOff and give it a value of 1

Comment: This doesn't work. All it does is remove the logoff button on the start menu, which is already hidden.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the registry to set this option on XP for either a user or the entire system:

User Key: [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\
Explorer]
System Key: [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\
Explorer]
Value Name: NoLogOff
Data Type: REG_DWORD (DWORD Value)
Value Data: (1 = no log off, 0 = show log off)

Also you can use the policies setting to enforce this see this article from MS to use policy settings:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/292504

Comment: This doesn't work. All it does is remove the logoff button on the start menu, which is already hidden.

Comment: Is your system up to date and you have service pack 3?

Comment: Yes. But as I said, the logoff button has already been removed, so this is not applicable.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds promising >>[instructions here](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/remove-log-off-button-start-menu-t3789504.html)<<

Comment: This doesn't work. All it does is remove the logoff button on the start menu, which is already hidden.

Comment: I thought Windows changed the layout you're describing with updates. Can you show a screen shot?