# Windows XP stay logged in

Tags: windows, windows-xp, login, shutdown, logoff

Is there a way to make Windows XP stay logged in even after the user logs off? Right now the PCs log in at start up and we're using WinOFF to shut down the computer after X minutes of inactivity.

The problem is that WinOFF does not work when the user logs off and stays in the "Select user login" screen.

I'm thinking a possible solution would be to make the computer log back in as the default user after Y minutes of inactivity.  How can I make it so that Windows XP logs in automatically after the user logs off?

Comment: Not the same question, but see my answer here:

[http://superuser.com/a/456966/65708][1]


  [1]: http://superuser.com/a/456966/65708

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better solution would be to have WinOFF run in the system domain instead of in the user domain. That way, it is run independent of who is or is not logged in.

Where do you have WinOFF autorunning? In the Startup folder? In the Run key? Wherever it is, take it out and put it in `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`.

Another option is to [create](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251192) [a Windows](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137890) [service](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfx64bit/thread/b6f52aae-c1cb-4b57-8d82-6aa5ba18441a) to run it (make sure to set its type as `interactive` and start as auto). For example:

```
sc create WinOff binpath= c:\…\winoff.exe start= auto type= own type= interact displayname= "Auto WinOff"
sc description WinOff "Run WinOff in the system domain to automatically shut down whether any users are logged in or not."
```

Comment: Are you sure that making it run as SYSTEM will work? I tried changing the registry as you mentioned but WinOFF still does not seem to work.  If you're sure it works, maybe I did something wrong.

Comment: Programs that are auto-run via user locations (the user’s copy of the `Startup` folder or the user’s `Run` key) will cause them to run *when the user logs in*. Programs that are auto-run via system locations (the global `Startup` folder or the HKLM `Run` key) are run *on boot*. If it’s not working for some reason, you can do some testing to find out why, but it may be easier to just install it as a service which should guarantee that it runs even before anyone logs in.

Comment: Ok I can get it to run as a service but it doesn't save any of the settings like Autostart at start up without inputting the password each time.  Or shutdown after X minutes.  It's all reset to default.

Comment: Why do you have to save the setting each time? You should be able to run it with admin privileges once, configure it, and have it run with those settings. What may be happening however is that if it is saving the settings to the HKCU branch (the user-specific registry branch), then when it runs in the system domain, it is finding that there are no settings and prompting you to run it. In that case, you should be able to run it and configure it by “running” it by starting the service manually after logging in (e.g. `net start WinOff`) and configuring it then.

Comment: On initial log on, the password prompt comes up for the admin panel.  If I leave it alone, it will still shut off after X minutes of inactivity.  So it is kinda working as a service.  However it still does not work when I log off and when I log back in, the WinOFF service isn't working anymore.  I've set the inactivity to 1 minute for testing and it just won't shut off after logging off and logging back in but it does on initial log on.

Comment: What [service account](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686005(v=vs.85).aspx) is it currently set to? You can set the username and password for the service so that it doesn’t prompt you or fail to run when it doesn’t get the login information. You can do it [from the command-line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308298/how-to-set-windows-service-username-and-password-through-commandline) or more easily with the [Services snapin (`services.msc`)](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/125652).

Comment: Well I created the service as the default user (the public account) but I thought the point was to make the service run in the SYSTEM?

Comment: Yes, you want it to run in the system context. You can change the user to SYSTEM (and provide the admin password) in the Services snap in.